# lsi megaraid 9260 single raid0 disk went unconfigured bad, please help recover data

Tags: lsi, megaraid, raid0

I had some problem with my server with lsi megaraid 9260 chip(no JBOD support). I cannot recall exactly but I think I had a single drive as r0, and it failed. I need to recover data from it, if possible. I'll describe what happened:

One day when I was working over SSH all my vms went down and the last thing I could get was

```
root@localhost:~# busybox sh
Bus error
root@localhost:~# busybox reboot
root@localhost:~# busybox reboot
root@localhost:~# busybox reboot 
root@localhost:~# busybox reboot --help
Bus error
root@localhost:~# busybox reboot -f
Write failed: Broken pipe
```

Couldn't get dmesg. I know I should've done it with busybox as it was likely working... Cant tell now.
Back to problem: what I did next: I managed to mark it good again, now it's status is `Unconfigured(good), Spun up`

Drive LED is not red anymore.

Can I recover it and how? Currently I can't see it in /dev/ fs. The data there is pretty valuable. I know I should have had backups but it was all created in a course of few workdays without really concentrating on making this server production and setting up backups mechanism. No backups kept. What could be done with this drive? I do guess correctly that if I add it to any raid group right now I will lose all info there?

What steps can I take? What info should I provide?
Thanks in advance.

-- update from answer

My current layout is:

**disk 0** - "foreign", "unconfigured (good), spun up", was RAID0 single drive until "failed" and became "unconfigured (bad)" which I was lucky to be able to make "unconfigured (good)" now.

**disk 1** and **disk 2** are in RAID1 group, working good.

third slot is empty.

-- solution to problem is provided by Matt Dytkowski, with WebBIOS usage. I did **NOT** try the **megacli**! I used a foreign config import offered by WebBIOS as it was representing my supposed and most likely config of two groups, r1 and r0.

I remember one of drives simply went "Unconfigured (bad)" and there was no way to mark it good - it just wouldn't become "good". Had to trash it. This one doesn't feel good now but at least I can read it. In some places.

Comment: I don't know what you expected while running without RAID protection.

Comment: a trouble to come. it was actually not intended to use it that much, was just a dump server for small runtime tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ohh and if the drive is shown as unconfigured good now. There is a trick to get your data back - just recreate RAID 0 with the same parameters as you had earlier and when it asks you to Initialize the array just say NO.

It will create new config on a drive but won't wipe it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, it's unconf good. I was using megacli the last time, not webbios, and the command to make it was probably some fork of hetzner's manual, https://wiki.hetzner.de/index.php/LSI_RAID_Controller/en

Comment: i think it was a mod of `megacli -CfgEachDskRaid0 WB RA Direct CachedBadBBU -a0` but not all disks to raid0, just one. should my command look like `megacli -CfgLdAdd -r0 [252:0] WB RA Direct CachedBadBBU -a0` after I reset forgeign config?

Comment: My current disk layout is 252:1 and 252:2 are virtual drive 0, raid 1, not having anything except debian with megaraid. boots perfectly. Also there was, I believe, virtual drive 1 which consisted of only single r0 drive 252:0, which is now "unconfigured (good)". WebBIOS says (in "controller selection" -> 0 -> ) "Foreign configs found, want to import?" and dropdown menu "AllConfigurations" and "Configuration1". If i go to preview of "All", it supposedly shows me my previous layout, with raid1 and raid0 kept(although no specification of which physical drives used for which "drive group").

Comment: Shall I try importing it like that in WebBIOS?

Comment: It worked, imported foreign thru webbios solved the problem, drive is now accessible. Thank you very very much. BTC donation address is welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

If your array failed then you can try to push the drive online. In the WEBbios go select affected drive and make online.

When it kicks in, try to boot and backup your data immediately.

Comment: I still have it as foreign configuration, and not in any groups, will that action make it available to linux as /dev/sd* device?